# UV-C lamps flickering problem

Tags: ac, battery-operated, lamp, uv, ballast

I have got 8 UV-C lamps connected to a [portable battery(AC)](https://www.amazon.co.jp/Appliances-Refrigerator-Conditioning-Simultaneously-Heatstroke/dp/B088LXW81X/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?crid=2RGY36XRCE086&dchild=1&keywords=bluetti&qid=1617718387&sprefix=bluetti%2Caps%2C286&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExSVdaM1RRSEZNQlNDJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwOTM2MjQ0M0o3OEdUQUlBUFhZRyZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEzNUxMNlUzSUpKTUpIJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==) through a [smartplug](https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/TP-Link-Certified-Multicolor-Additional-Required/dp/B07FY4GDDQ/ref=sr_1_1?crid=280NUDARAPRFW&dchild=1&keywords=tplink%20smart%20plug&qid=1617718498&sprefix=tplink%20smar%2Caps%2C495&sr=8-1). I am using 4 [UV Ballast](http://www.beasun.com/english/rh2_425_2_40u.html) with 2 lamps connected to one ballast. I am controlling the lamps with help of a wireless controller which involves periodic switching on and off.
When everything was new it was working absolutely fine, now the entire unit is 5months old and there is a frequent flickering of UV lamps. when i turn ON the UV light using the controller, it extinguishes automatically now and then But when i turn it ON again after sometime it again extinguishes. I am trying to debug what the problem is but I am not able to figure out the exact reason[image].

The specification of battery, UV ballast are in the respective links.
Specification of the UV-C Lamps:
Standard voltage AC100 / 200V
Discharge start electricity pressure 94%
Lamp current 0.800 ± 0.050 A
Lamp pressure 92 V
Lamp power 67 W

It would be really helpful if someone can give their insights.
Upon serious research I also came to know that UV ballasts shelf life decreases with more we switch ON/OFF the lamps. Is this maybe the reason?

Comment: Lamps do go out over time. Ballasts last a very long time.

Comment: thank you @Hearth.. But the manufacturer stated that the shelf life of the lamp is 8000 hours and its been used way less than that..

Comment: two notes: 1) Shelf life is how long the thing stays good when you're not using it at all, and probably isn't what you mean here; these lamps have unlimited shelf life. 2) gas discharge lamps, especially the "instant-on" ones that don't take a few seconds to turn on, have their useful life shortened *significantly* more by turning them on and off once than by leaving them on for hours at a time.

Comment: sorry i Meant Rating life, not shelf life. Thanks a lot, very helpful. Also Is there a reason why the bottom of the lamps turn black(like a carbon coated) after using quite sometime?

Comment: That's sputtering of the electrodes. Actually, that's exactly what I was talking about when I said the "instant on" lamps are more damaged by turning on; those  turn on more aggressively which causes additional electrode sputtering, which damages the electrode. It's literally bits of the electrode being blown off and ending up on the outer tube.

Comment: Have you evaluated switching to LEDs?

Comment: is this kind of lamp usage a dangerous practice for the person using it? What type of UV-C lamps can I use in such situations where i need to switch ON/OFF?

Comment: NO, i have not tried with LEDs yet since I was looking for a solution for this current setup.

Comment: does using UV-C LEDs prevent this problem?

Comment: UV-C is harmful to eyes.  Even a tri-phosphor 32W 4’ tube rated for 30kh will last more than 50kh if left on instead of on/off every day so more rapid periodic cycles and poor matching of two 67W tubes to a 80W ballast means the  ballast will extinguish the tube after it warms up due to loss of permeability,  use 1 tube only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

It is gas discharge lamp, similar to regular luminescent lamp. That type of fixture does not work good then switching on-off happens very often. That brings them down very quickly. Ballast is not affected much, especially electronics, but tubes is.

Comment: How can I improve it? Also manufacturer note is that shelf life of lamp is 8000 hours and I dont think it has been even 4000hours.

Comment: Keep it works longer, one-off rarely. Use some timer.  For example your schedule 2min on, 10-off, keep it works all 12 minutes. Shelf life you may achieve if you did not turn it off, works permanently.

Comment: you mean keep supplying the current to it always and switch it ON/OFF for a specific time in between?

Comment: Understood.. Thank you

Comment: Yes, consider every on-off reduce the lifetime by 10 hours( not exact timing). Similar principal lamp used for street light and wok for years but when I applied one for air duct disinfection, switched on only the fan on, it is gone after couple months.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs....Helped alot

Comment: You did not comment on the power mismatch of tubes to ballast (-2) but true all tubes degrade with each start, like incandescants